# React & Rails 6 Project Tracking Clients that belong to Users by both unique IDs / API, Routes, and Passing variable to html.erb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, variable-assignment, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating a database (I'm a newb) with React, Ruby on Rails 6, and using jbuilder for the JSON responses. Every User that is created has clients. Those Users that create clients can only view their clients that they create. In the add_client.jsx file, when a User clicks the "add client" button, a new client is posted to the database (so far that's been working no problem) and they are redirected to the new page "client.html.erb." I am trying to organize it where, the information they entered in the previous page now displays that client information, like a client profile page, that can be edited and called upon later. I can successfully log new clients to the database, but when I am routed to the new page it is blank. My console seems to point to my API call, saying the "id" (for the client) doesn't exist.

Here are the routes setup so far...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
    # STATIC PAGES - FRONT END!
    get '/:username/add_clients'    => 'static_pages#add_client' # page for adding client
    get '/:username/clients'        => 'static_pages#client' # Renders clients by user profile page
  namespace :api do
    # USERS
    resources :users, only: [:create]
    # SESSIONS
    post '/sessions'                                => 'sessions#create'
    get  '/authenticated'                           => 'sessions#authenticated'
    delete '/sessions'                              => 'sessions#destroy'
    #CLIENTS
    post '/clients'                                 => 'clients#create'                 
    get '/clients/:id'                              => 'clients#show'
    get '/clients/'                                 => 'clients#index'                
  end
end
```

Here is the "Add_Clients.jsx" file, which does successfully create new clients...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from '@src/layout';
import { safeCredentials, handleErrors } from '@utils/fetchHelper';

class AddClient extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      age: '',
      spouse_first_name: '',
      spouse_last_name: '',
      spouse_age: '',
      retirement_year: '',
      error: '',
      username: '',
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleGoBack = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const redirect_url = params.get('redirect_url') || '/';
        window.location = redirect_url;
  };


  addClient = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const clientData = {
      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      age: this.state.age,
      spouse_first_name: this.state.spouse_first_name,
      spouse_last_name: this.state.spouse_last_name,
      spouse_age: this.state.spouse_age,
      retirement_year: this.state.retirement_year,
    };

    fetch(`/api/clients`, safeCredentials({
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client: clientData,
      })
    }))
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data:', data);
      this.setState({
        username: data.client.user.username,
      })

      const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
      // Use this.state.username instead of user.username
      const redirect_url = params.get('redirect_url') || `/${this.state.username}/clients/`
      window.location = redirect_url;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({
        error: 'Sorry, you cannot create a new client, Please try again.'
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { first_name, last_name, age, spouse_first_name, spouse_last_name, spouse_age, retirement_year, error } = this.state;

    return(
      <Layout>
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.addClient}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="first_name">First name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="first_name"
                value={this.state.first_name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="last_name">Last name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="last_name"
                value={this.state.last_name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                name="age"
                value={this.state.age}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="spouse_first_name">Spouse's first name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="spouse_first_name"
                value={this.state.spouse_first_name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="spouse_last_name">Spouse's last name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="spouse_last_name"
                value={this.state.spouse_last_name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="spouse_age">Spouse's Age</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                name="spouse_age"
                value={this.state.spouse_age}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="retirement_year">Retirement year</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                name="retirement_year"
                value={this.state.retirement_year}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.handleGoBack}
              >
                Go Back
              </button>
            <button>Add a new client</button>    
              {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Layout>
    )
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
      <AddClient />,
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
});
```

Here is the code for the "client.jsx" file, where they user is meant to be routed to when they create a new client, to view that new information as a profile page..

```
// client.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from '@src/layout';
import { handleErrors } from '@utils/fetchHelper';

class ClientProfile extends React.Component {
  state = {
    client: {},
    loading: true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/api/clients/${client_id}`)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        client: data.client,
        loading: false,
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { client, loading } = this.state;
    if(loading) {
      return <p>loading...</p>
    };

    const {
      id,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      age,
      spouse_first_name,
      spouse_last_name,
      spouse_age,
      retirement_year,
      user,
    } = client

    return(
    <Layout>
      <div className='client mb-3 container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-12'>
            <div className='profile'>{first_name}<span></span>{last_name}</div>
            <div>{age}</div>
            <div className='spouse'>{spouse_first_name}<span></span>{spouse_last_name}</div>
            <div>{spouse_age}</div>
            <div className='retirement'>{retirement_year}</div>
            <div client_id={id} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Layout>
      )
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const node = document.getElementById('params');
  const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data-params'));

  ReactDOM.render(
    <ClientProfile Client_id={data.client_id} />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

Here is the Static_Pages controller code, and the relevant Client controller code...

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render 'home'
  end
  def add_client
    render 'add_clients'
  end
  def client
    @data = { client_id: params[:id] }.to_json
    render 'client'
  end
end
```

```
module Api
  class ClientsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @clients = Client.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(6)
      return render json: { error: 'not_found' }, status: :not_found if !@clients
      render 'api/clients/index', status: :ok  
    end
    def show
      @client = Client.find_by(id: params[:id])
      return render json: { error: 'not_found' }, status: :not_found if !@client
      render 'api/clients/show', status: :ok
    end
    def create
      token = cookies.signed[:bucket_session_token]
      session = Session.find_by(token: token)
      user = session.user
      @client = user.clients.new(client_params)
      if @client.save
        render 'api/clients/create'
      end
    end
        def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :age, :spouse_first_name, :spouse_last_name, :spouse_age, :retirement_year, :user)
    end
  end
end
```

client.html.erb view file....

```
<%= javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag 'client', 'application' %>
<%= stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag 'client', 'application' %>
<div id="params" data-params="<%= @data %>"></div>
```

Show.jbuilder view file in app/view/clients

```
json.client do
  json.id   @client.id
  json.first_name   @client.first_name
  json.last_name    @client.last_name
  json.age  @client.age
  json.spouse_first_name    @client.spouse_first_name
  json.spouse_last_name @client.spouse_last_name
  json.spouse_age   @client.spouse_age
  json.retirement_year  @client.retirement_year

  json.user do
    json.id @client.user.id
    json.username @client.user.username
  end
end
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I've tried everything I can think of but can't seem to get this to do what I want.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated (feel free to rip into me)